# 301 redirect to third party causing Ajax request to make duplicate calls

Tags: javascript, ajax, http-status-code-301, event-tracking

There are a lot of similar questions but I think I have a new twist on it.

I'm trying to call a third party url via ajax for tracking purposes, so I don't really care about the response. just that it's sent.

The tracking site has given us a url that they expect the user to click on which then does a 301 redirect to our product page. We want to show a modal window instead of redirecting to the product page, like a quick view button for instance.

The problem is that the browser is sending two requests to the original url which is going to skew our statistics.
Looking at the network panel in chrome I can see one is from jQuery's ajax function and has the call stack associated with it. The second request appears to come from a 'click' event.

If I remove the ajax request from the function then no requests are sent.

I've created a mock server for further testing. When it returned a 200 there was only one request sent. When I changed it to a 301 the two requests were sent.
The weird thing is that both requests are to the original URL. It's not even trying to following the redirect.

I'm a bit stuck and I'm hoping someone can give me some direction on what to try next.

This is the function that calls $.ajax:

```
function externalRequest(settings) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        $.ajax(settings)
            .done((data, textStatus, jqXHR) => {
                const { status, statusText } = jqXHR;

                resolve({
                    data,
                    status,
                    statusText,
                });
            })
            .fail(reject);
    });
}
```

Generic third party tagging function:

```
function thirdPartyTracking(url) {
    Ajax.externalRequest({
        method: 'GET',
        url,
    }).catch((error) => {
        console.error('Error sending tracking tag: ', url, error);
    });
}
```

This is called like:

```
thirdPartyTracking('https://tracking.com/click?sku=123&uid=abc456')
```

Results on the network panel:

[image: requests in the network panel]

Thanks

Comment: Can you show the code that you have done?

Comment: _“The second request appears to come from a 'click' event.”_ - who should be doing that clicking, when we are talking about a _background_ process here …? (The URL you are making the request to contains the word `click`, are you sure you did not let that confuse you somehow here?) And can you not ask that tracking service to provide you with a URL that does _not_ redirect elsewhere to begin with? Different endpoint, additional parameter `&redirect=no`, anything like that?

Comment: I've added a screen shot of the network panel. It also gives a clue to the third party  tracking company in question.

Comment: did @CBroe's suggestion and asked the third party for a different URL